# Adding an array into HashMap

Tags: java, arrays, hashmap

I am trying to add an array to HashMap, however I cannot find a good solution. 
For now I have :

```
Person[] array;

public void add(Person p){

    HashMap<String, ArrayList<String>> people = 
    new HashMap <String, ArrayList<String>>();

    people.put("key", p);
```

However, the put method does not accept "p". 
I know I could also use loop to do this, however I am not sure how. I was thinking about sth like:

```
HashMap<String, ArrayList<String>> people = 
new HashMap <String, ArrayList<String>>();

map.put("key", new ArrayList<String>>());

for (int i=0;i<Person.size(); i++) {
    map.get("sth").add(Person[i]); 
}
```

What is another way to add elements of an array into the hash map? Or what should I change for any of the two to work? Thanks in advance, I'm just starting with Java so any help is highly appreciated!

Comment: How you expecting something of type ArrayList<String> to accept Person?

Comment: May you change it into `HashMap<String, Person> people = 
    new HashMap <String, Person>();` ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
HashMap<String, ArrayList<String>>
```

look at the generic type it is asking for a `list of strings` and you are trying to add a `person` , which will ofcource give an error.

you can change the `generic` on the `hashmap` to this

```
HashMap<String,Person> persons = new  HashMap<String,Person>();
```

then you can add a person to the `map` using `put` method

```
persons.put("key",person);
```

if you need to add an `array of persons` to the `map` you can do it with below approach.

```
public void foo(Person[] array){
        HashMap<String , Person[]> persons = new HashMap<String , Person[]>();
        persons.put("key", array);
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

An array is a different object than an `ArrayList`. I would suggest you use `List` or `ArrayList` all the time. For most purposes you do not need plain arrays.

Answer (score 0):

You need to make List or ArrayList of your Person before you can add it.

```
public void add(Person p){
ArrayList<Person> p1 = new ArrayList<>();

    HashMap<String, ArrayList<String>> people = new HashMap <>();

    people.put("key", p1.add(p));
```

Comment: Applying your answer I am getting error "The method put(Integer, ArrayList<String>) in the type HashMap<Integer,ArrayList<String>> is not applicable for the arguments (int, boolean)"

Comment: I made it HashMap<String,ArrayList<String>> so i think you should check the type of data you are putting, if is string or Integer and then change it.

Comment: Yes, I have integer now (and I changed everything accordingly) but I think it's the boolean that creates a problem. Why p1.add(p) is read as a boolean?

Comment: you can do the p1.add(p) outside and after that just di people.put("key",p1); this one should work the same.

Comment: still not, but I've found another solution. Thanks anyways!